# python selenium login slide bar

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I access the website and log-in manually, it works well. 
However, when I use *selenium webdriver* and try to log in, this login slide bar shows, so I can't log in.

This is my code as followed.

```
id = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#TPL_username_1').send_keys("prayjung50")

pw = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="TPL_password_1"]').send_keys("xxxxxxxxxxxx")

time.sleep(10)
login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="J_SubmitStatic"]').click()
```

This is the image of the website as followed.

[image]

This is the website code of slide bar as followed.

```
<!-- use new slide checkcode -->

<div id="nocaptcha" class="nc-container tb-login nc-tm-min-fix" data-nc-idx="1" style="display: block;">
    <div id="nc_1_wrapper" class="nc_wrapper">
      <div id="nc_1_n1t" class="nc_scale">
        <div id="nc_1__bg" class="nc_bg"></div>
        <span id="nc_1_n1z" class="nc_iconfont btn_slide"></span>
      <div id="nc_1__scale_text" class="scale_text slidetounlock"><span class="nc-lang-cnt" data-nc-lang="_startTEXT" data-spm-anchor-id="a2107.1.0.i0.3e3e11d9wfV1qj">请按住滑块，拖动到最右边</span></div>
      <div id="nc_1_clickCaptcha" class="clickCaptcha" style="top: -202px; height: 380px; min-height: 0px;">
      <div class="clickCaptcha_text">
      <b id="nc_1__captcha_text" class="nc_captch_text"></b>
      <i id="nc_1__btn_2" class="nc_iconfont nc_btn_2 btn_refresh"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="clickCaptcha_img"></div>
    <div class="clickCaptcha_btn"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="nc_1_imgCaptcha" class="imgCaptcha" style="top: -202px; height: 339px; min-height: 0px;">
      <div class="imgCaptcha_text"><input id="nc_1_captcha_input" maxlength="6" type="text" style="ime-mode:disabled"></div>
      <div class="imgCaptcha_img" id="nc_1__imgCaptcha_img"></div>
     <i id="nc_1__btn_1" class="nc_iconfont nc_btn_1 btn_refresh" onclick="document.getElementById('nc_1__imgCaptcha_img').children[0].click()"></i>
      <div class="imgCaptcha_btn">
      <div id="nc_1__captcha_img_text" class="nc_captcha_img_text"></div>
      <div id="nc_1_scale_submit" class="nc_scale_submit"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
      <div id="nc_1_cc" class="nc-cc"></div>
      <i id="nc_1__voicebtn" tabindex="0" role="button" class="nc_voicebtn nc_iconfont" style="display:none"></i>
    <b id="nc_1__helpbtn" class="nc_helpbtn"><span class="nc-lang-cnt" data-nc-lang="_learning">了解新功能</span></b>
  </div>
  <div id="nc_1__voice" class="nc_voice"></div>
  </div>
  </div>"a2107.1.0.i0.3e3e11d9wfV1qj">请按住滑块，拖动到最右边</span>
```

Comment: Does _selenium webdriver_ prompt any error?

Comment: When I did selenium, there is no errors. The slider bar only show. When I did it by manually, there is no slider bar.